Dynamic `URL.createObjectURL` import() causes failed to resolve module specifier
When I dynamically import a module, I can't import other modules relative to the website root from the root of the site.
const fileConents = `import { test } from "/some-path.js"`;

const blob = new Blob([fileContents], {
  type: "application/javascript"
});
const moduleUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
try {
  const importedModule = await import(moduleUrl);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
} finally {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(moduleUrl);
}

This causes the following error:
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "/some-path.js". Invalid relative url or base scheme isn't hierarchical.
Importing "/some-path.js" in static imports. Please advice how to fix this!

It does say Invalid relative url - and that blob you are using does not and cannot have access to the environment in that sense. It cannot import because it is not relative to anything, and in essence, not even on the page. MDN explictely warns "That is, import x from "data:text/javascript,import y from './y.js';" will throw an error because the relative specifier './y.js' cannot be resolved.". Blob URLS are not mentioned as an option, but JS data URLs are so I'm assuming blobs work, but I have not tried this.

@somethinghere When I log import.meta.url I also get an error. Is there any way to set where URLs should be loaded from?

Seems likely? The import has no url as a source I think. It's just a self contained blob with a location inside your cache?

I have used a regex to replace / to change it to a https:// path.
const fileConents = `import { test } from "/some-path.js"`
  .replaceAll(/(^import [^"]+")\//gm, `$1${window.origin}/`);

